# setAutoIndentStyle() on the QScintilla lexer doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, scintilla, qscintilla

Automatic indentation is a very nice feature offered by QScintilla. When inserting a new line, automatic indentation pushes the cursor to the same indentation level as the previous one:

[image]

**1. Without lexer**
If you did NOT install a lexer, you can easily turn this feature on like so:

```
self.__editor.setAutoIndent(True)
```

`self.__editor` in this codeline is an instance of `QsciScintilla()`, so it represents the actual editor in my code.

**2. With lexer**
Even if you activate a lexer, the previous approach will still work. But it's not a very good practice, because the lexer might override that setting. So the better approach would be to remove the previous codeline, and switch on auto indentation in the lexer:

```
class MyLexer(QsciLexerCustom):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyLexer, self).__init__(parent)
        [...]
        self.setAutoIndentStyle(QsciScintilla.AiMaintain)
    ''''''

    def language(self):
        [...]
    ''''''

    def description(self, style):
        [...]
    ''''''

    def styleText(self, start, end):
        [...]
    ''''''

'''--- end class ---'''
```

Another advantage of this approach is the bigger flexibility. Switching on auto indentation in the lexer lets you choose between (or even combine):

- `QsciScintilla.AiOpening`
- `QsciScintilla.AiClosing`
- `QsciScintilla.AiMaintain`

**3. The problem**
The approach as described in the first paragraph **without lexer** works. The approach desribed in the second paragraph **with lexer** doesn't. No matter which setting I choose as parameter to `setAutoIndentStyle(..)`, nothing changes.
Why?

**4. A full example to experiment**
Here is an example to experiment. Just copy-paste it in a `.py` file and run it. You should get a working editor with some simple syntax highlighting. You can use it to experiment with the auto indentation:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qsci import *
import re


class MyLexer(QsciLexerCustom):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyLexer, self).__init__(parent)

        # Default text settings
        # ----------------------
        self.setDefaultColor(QColor("#ff000000"))
        self.setDefaultPaper(QColor("#ffffffff"))
        self.setDefaultFont(QFont("Consolas", 14))

        # Initialize colors per style
        # ----------------------------
        self.setColor(QColor("#ff000000"), 0)   # Style 0: black
        self.setColor(QColor("#ff7f0000"), 1)   # Style 1: red
        self.setColor(QColor("#ff0000bf"), 2)   # Style 2: blue
        self.setColor(QColor("#ff007f00"), 3)   # Style 3: green

        # Initialize paper colors per style
        # ----------------------------------
        self.setPaper(QColor("#ffffffff"), 0)   # Style 0: white
        self.setPaper(QColor("#ffffffff"), 1)   # Style 1: white
        self.setPaper(QColor("#ffffffff"), 2)   # Style 2: white
        self.setPaper(QColor("#ffffffff"), 3)   # Style 3: white

        # Initialize fonts per style
        # ---------------------------
        self.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14, weight=QFont.Bold), 0)   # Style 0: Consolas 14pt
        self.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14, weight=QFont.Bold), 1)   # Style 1: Consolas 14pt
        self.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14, weight=QFont.Bold), 2)   # Style 2: Consolas 14pt
        self.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14, weight=QFont.Bold), 3)   # Style 3: Consolas 14pt

        # Auto indent
        # ------------
        #self.setAutoIndentStyle(QsciScintilla.AiOpening | QsciScintilla.AiClosing)
        self.setAutoIndentStyle(QsciScintilla.AiMaintain)
        print(self.autoIndentStyle())

    ''''''

    def language(self):
        return "SimpleLanguage"
    ''''''

    def description(self, style):
        if style == 0:
            return "myStyle_0"
        elif style == 1:
            return "myStyle_1"
        elif style == 2:
            return "myStyle_2"
        elif style == 3:
            return "myStyle_3"
        ###
        return ""
    ''''''

    def styleText(self, start, end):
        # 1. Initialize the styling procedure
        # ------------------------------------
        self.startStyling(start)

        # 2. Slice out a part from the text
        # ----------------------------------
        text = self.parent().text()[start:end]

        # 3. Tokenize the text
        # ---------------------
        p = re.compile(r"[*]\/|\/[*]|\s+|\w+|\W")

        # 'token_list' is a list of tuples: (token_name, token_len)
        token_list = [ (token, len(bytearray(token, "utf-8"))) for token in p.findall(text)]

        # 4. Style the text
        # ------------------
        # 4.1 Check if multiline comment
        multiline_comm_flag = False
        editor = self.parent()
        if start > 0:
            previous_style_nr = editor.SendScintilla(editor.SCI_GETSTYLEAT, start - 1)
            if previous_style_nr == 3:
                multiline_comm_flag = True
            ###
        ###
        # 4.2 Style the text in a loop
        for i, token in enumerate(token_list):
            if multiline_comm_flag:
                self.setStyling(token[1], 3)
                if token[0] == "*/":
                    multiline_comm_flag = False
                ###
            ###
            else:
                if token[0] in ["for", "while", "return", "int", "include"]:
                    # Red style
                    self.setStyling(token[1], 1)

                elif token[0] in ["(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "#"]:
                    # Blue style
                    self.setStyling(token[1], 2)

                elif token[0] == "/*":
                    multiline_comm_flag = True
                    self.setStyling(token[1], 3)

                else:
                    # Default style
                    self.setStyling(token[1], 0)
                ###
            ###
        ###

    ''''''

''' end Class '''




myCodeSample = r"""#include <stdio.h>
/*
 * This is a
 * multiline
 * comment */
int main()
{
    char arr[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}""".replace("\n","\r\n")




class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #

        # 1. Define the geometry of the main window
        # ------------------------------------------
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("QScintilla Test")

        # 2. Create frame and layout
        # ---------------------------
        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffeaeaea }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)
        self.__myFont = QFont()
        self.__myFont.setPointSize(14)

        # 3. Place a button
        # ------------------
        self.__btn = QPushButton("Qsci")
        self.__btn.setFixedWidth(50)
        self.__btn.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.__btn.clicked.connect(self.__btn_action)
        self.__btn.setFont(self.__myFont)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__btn)

        # -------------------------------- #
        #     QScintilla editor setup      #
        # -------------------------------- #

        # ! Make instance of QSciScintilla class!
        # ----------------------------------------
        self.__editor = QsciScintilla()
        self.__editor.setText(myCodeSample)     # 'myCodeSample' is a string containing some C-code
        self.__editor.setLexer(None)            # We install lexer later
        self.__editor.setUtf8(True)             # Set encoding to UTF-8
        self.__editor.setFont(self.__myFont)    # Gets overridden by lexer later on

        # 1. Text wrapping
        # -----------------
        self.__editor.setWrapMode(QsciScintilla.WrapWord)
        self.__editor.setWrapVisualFlags(QsciScintilla.WrapFlagByText)
        self.__editor.setWrapIndentMode(QsciScintilla.WrapIndentIndented)

        # 2. End-of-line mode
        # --------------------
        self.__editor.setEolMode(QsciScintilla.EolWindows)
        self.__editor.setEolVisibility(False)

        # 3. Indentation
        # ---------------
        self.__editor.setIndentationsUseTabs(False)
        self.__editor.setTabWidth(4)
        self.__editor.setIndentationGuides(True)
        self.__editor.setTabIndents(True)
        #self.__editor.setAutoIndent(True)   <- This is set in the lexer!!!

        # 4. Caret
        # ---------
        self.__editor.setCaretForegroundColor(QColor("#ff0000ff"))
        self.__editor.setCaretLineVisible(True)
        self.__editor.setCaretLineBackgroundColor(QColor("#1f0000ff"))
        self.__editor.setCaretWidth(2)

        # 5. Margins
        # -----------
        # Margin 0 = Line nr margin
        self.__editor.setMarginType(0, QsciScintilla.NumberMargin)
        self.__editor.setMarginWidth(0, "0000")
        self.__editor.setMarginsForegroundColor(QColor("#ff888888"))

        # -------------------------------- #
        #          Install lexer           #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.__lexer = MyLexer(self.__editor)
        self.__editor.setLexer(self.__lexer)

        # ! Add editor to layout !
        # -------------------------
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__editor)
        self.show()

    ''''''

    def __btn_action(self):
        print("Hello World!")
    ''''''

''' End Class '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

''''''
```

I have taken this example (and slightly adapted it to the needs of this question) from my website on QScintilla: https://qscintilla.com/custom-lexer-example/

**5. Notes**
For the sake of completeness, this is my system:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6
- QScintilla 2.10 or higher

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to the scintilla lexer, the 1st being for the syntax colorization, the 2nd for indentation.

The example you are using is only for syntax coloring.

I have not used the python implementation of QScintilla, so am not sure if the functions are available in python, however in C++, you can use indentLine in your lexer to set it, or set the begin and endblock keywords of the lexer to let qscintilla do it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. + 1 for your interesting answer!

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "two parts to the lexer"? Please feel free to give any example in C++. I can translate most of that to Python 

Comment: I am not even sure if it is possible to implment in python that way, but for a C++ lexer, one of the most complete is perhaps LexerCPP (Qt4Qt5/qscilexercpp.cpp in qscintilla source code) which contains QsciLexerCPP::blockStart and QsciLexerCPP::blockEnd functions

Comment: The 2 parts just means that the main function of scintilla is the symtax colorization of the code. Secondaty, you can set the indent levels as well. For examples, the CPP lexer in qscintilla uses the start/end block words for indenting, the matlab lexer explicitly sets the indenting